# Seleccionar valor de un dropdownlist y llenar texbox

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, webforms

Tengo un dropdownlist que equivale al producto, este producto ya esta en la BD y tiene su respectivo precio, quiero que al seleccionar el x producto en un textbox se llene automaticamente con el precio de ese producto

Comment: Puedes poner lo que has intentado?

Answer (score 2):

El dropwonlist tiene un evento que es el OnSelectedIndexChanged . Debes crear el metodo que escuche a ese evento.

Ejemplo:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="productos"
                    AutoPostBack="True"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="Selection_Change"
                    runat="server">

                  <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="1"> Producto1 </asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem Value="2"> Producto2 </asp:ListItem>

                   Lista cargada desde base de datos....
               </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtprecio"  runat="server"/>
```

Y en tu code behind....

```
void Selection_Change(Object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

    int id=productos.SelectedItem.Value

    //Consulta en la BD con el ID obtenido del dropdown

    txtprecio.text=(precio del producto obtenido desde la base de datos)     

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución de Aritz es buena, lo único que hará que se refresque la página. Si no quieres eso, puedes usar el atributo onchange para llamar a una función javascript que a su vez haga una llamada ajax:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="productos"
                onchange="selectionChange(this)"
                runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectionChange(ddl) {
        var selectedValue = ddl.value
        /* llamada ajax a BD y en el "success" rellenas el textbox */
    }
</script>
```